# Different content value of pseudo element basing on input type atribute

Tags: html, css, input, types, pseudo-element

i would like to have different content of ::before pseudo element for each input type atribute

i mean:
if mark up looks like this (**type="email"**)

```
<input type="email" name="foo" />
<label for="foo">
  <span>Email</span>
</label>
```

i would like to make the content value **$icon1**

```
span::before {
  content: $icon1;
}
```

but if mark up looks like this (**type="password"**)

```
<input type="password" name="foo-foo" />
<label for="foo-foo">
  <span>Password</span>
</label>
```

i would like to make content value make **$icon2**

```
span::before {
  content: $icon2;
}
```

i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: it might work but I reckon the css atribute selector [type="text"] might be used somehow, different classnames is not very professional in that case, i believe it's only about some operators thats why i ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine with attribute selector.

```css
input[type=email]+label span::before {
  content: "email input";
}

input[type=password]+label span::before {
  content: "password input";
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="foo" />
<label for="foo">
      <span></span>
</label>

<input type="password" name="foo-foo" />
<label for="foo-foo">
      <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: thanks! that's what i've been looking for, the "+" operator! +1